# output dictionary data as a table in console

Tags: python

I would like to output dict data in the form of a table in the console:

`dtc={ "test_case1_short":{"test_step11":"pass","test_step12":"pass","test_step_13":{"status":"failed","details":"ca marche po"},
          "test_case2_longest_name":{"test_step21":"ne","test_step22":"ne"},
          "test_case3_medium_name":{"test_step31":"ne","test_step32":"ne"} }`

note: for french speakers 'dtc' is a shortcut for dict_test_collection (!)

To build this table I would like to determine the size of key names in order to dimension my column headers.
I can get my key names max length doing this:

```
max = 0
for i in list(dtc.keys()):
if max < len(i):
    max = len(i)
print(max)
```

but I find this not very straighforward ... is there a way to get this information from dict.keys() or another dict feature ?

Besides, I'd like to set separators like "+-----------------------------+" for section headers and "|               |" for section bodies, to have a good looking table.
In section bodies, is there a straight and simple way to set the table and columns width (ie. '|' caracter ending up at column 50, whatever the text on the line, like padding the line with spaces until a certain column)

Thank you

Alexandre

Comment: Related to your second question, about table decoration, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9535954/printing-lists-as-tabular-data

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is there a way to get this information from dict.keys() or another dict feature ?

This seems straightforward to me:

```
max_key_len = max(len(key) for key in dtc)
print(max_key_len)
```

This one seems less straightforward, but it is shorter:

```
max_key_len = max(map(len, dtc))
print(max_key_len)
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, but I have a TypeError: 'int' object is not callable. If I do  [len(key) for key in dtc] I can get length values but I cannot apply max() on it ...

Comment: You've redefined the `max` function somewhere previously in your code. Try not to name your variables after built-in functions. Or, `import builtins` and then use `builtins.max(len(key) for key in dtc)`.